# Problems accessing Apache vhost in Vagrant

Tags: apache, vagrant, virtualhost

I have Apache server running on Ubuntu in a Vagrant box. In my `sites-available` directory I have two files:

**cats.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName cats.com
    ServerAlias cats.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/cats.com
</VirtualHost>
```

**dogs.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dogs.com
    ServerAlias dogs.test
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dogs.com
</VirtualHost>
```

In Vagrant I have this port forwarding set up:

```
Host IP   | Host Port | Guest IP  | Guest Port
----------------------------------------------
127.0.0.2 | 8000      | 10.0.2.15 | 80
```

In my `hosts` file:

```
127.0.0.2 cats.test
127.0.0.2 dogs.test
```

But when I visit `cats.test` in my browser, it can't connect.

Comment: Does your site respond when you test if from within the ubuntu machine?  If it does, from your server you must go to `http://cats.test:8080/` since you port forward port 8080 of the server to port 80 of Ubuntu.

Comment: That's the answer, thanks! If you want to write it up I'll mark it correct.

Comment: Glad it helped, done for the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your site does responds correctly when you test it from your Ubuntu VM itself, then it is missing the port in the URL.

https on the Ubuntu VM listens on port 80.  When you specified the Vagrant port forwarding:

```
Host IP   | Host Port | Guest IP  | Guest Port
----------------------------------------------
127.0.0.2 | 8000      | 10.0.2.15 | 80
```

it told Vagrant to listen to port 8080, and forward traffic to port 80 of the Ubuntu VM.

Thus on your host system, you have to point your browser to `http://cats.test:8080/`.

Info: when you connect to a web site with `http://example.com/`, it defaults to port 80 (http://).  For `https://example.com/` it defaults to port 443.  But http traffic can be handled on any port.  You specify the port with `:PORT` following the domain you want to access.